# Changing one specific word to another word throughout the whole document maintaining case

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement

I'm new to JavaScript and I just can't figure out this one thing...

I'm trying to change the specific word "katt" to "smurf" throughout the whole webpage. Every single "katt" is within a "span" tag and I can change it using this code:

```
for(var i=0;i<100;i++) {
    changeCat = document.getElementsByTagName("span")[i].innerHTML = "smurf";
}
```

The problem is though that every single "smurf" is now only in lowercase letters, even if it's at the beginning of a sentence. I do know I need an if/else to solve my problem but I have no idea how to code it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [javascript if..else](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Instructions/if...else)

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the word has its first letter capitalized with an `if...else` statement:

```js
let items = document.querySelectorAll('span')

for(let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {

  if(items[i].innerHTML == 'Hello') {
    items[i].innerHTML = 'Bye'
  } else if(items[i].innerHTML == 'hello') {
  items[i].innerHTML = 'bye'
  }
  
}
```

```html
<span>Hello</span><br />
<span>Nope</span><br />
<span>Hel-lo</span><br />
<span>Yes</span><br />
```

Or even shorter since the logic is simple, you can use a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```
let items = document.querySelectorAll('span')

for(let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {

  items[i].innerHTML = (items[i].innerHTML == 'Hello') ? 'Bye' else 'bye'

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this ?

```js
var span = document.getElementsByTagName("span");

for (var i = 0; i < span.length; i++) {
  //span[i].innerHTML = "smurf"; 
  // OR
  span[i].innerHTML = span[i].innerHTML.replace(/katt/gi, 'smurf');
}
```

```html
<span>hey katt hello</span><br/>
<span>hey katt hello</span><br/>
<i>hey katt hello</i><br/>
<span>hey katt hello</span><br/>
<span>hey katt hello</span><br/>
<b>hey katt hello</b><br/>
<span>hey katt hello</span><br/>
<span>katt hey katt hello</span><br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply check if the first letter is capitalized:

```js
function changeWords() {
  var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span');

  for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
    if (spans[i].innerText[0] == spans[i].innerText[0].toUpperCase()) {
      spans[i].innerText = "Smurf";
    } else {
      spans[i].innerText = "smurf";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<span>Katt</span>
<br> Some stuff <span>katt</span>
<br>
<span>Katt</span> other stuff
<br>
<button onclick="changeWords()">Let the magic happen!</button>
```

You also should use `element.length` instead of a hardcoded number. If the number is too high or too low, your script will get buggy.

If you just want to modify text, you should use `innerText`.

---

Without the function and the button (which is only to show the result), the code looks like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
  if (spans[i].innerText[0] == spans[i].innerText[0].toUpperCase()) {
    spans[i].innerText = "Smurf";
  } else {
    spans[i].innerText = "smurf";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, let me borrow some code from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1144788/125981

Which case do you wish to match to what? two examples:

```js
function escapeRegExp(str) {
  return str.replace(/([.*+?^=!:${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, "\\$1");
}

function replaceAll(str, find, replace) {
  return str.replace(new RegExp(escapeRegExp(find), 'g'), replace);
}

function changeem(oldtext, newtext) {
  var allspans = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
  for (let i = 0; i < allspans.length; i++) {
    allspans[i].innerHTML = replaceAll(allspans[i].innerHTML, oldtext, newtext);
  }
}
// the case you need to match and change to:
changeem("smurf", "cat");
// upper only?
changeem("Smurf", "Dog");
```

```css
span {
  border: solid lime 1px;
}
```

```html
<span>I smurf this smurf</span>
<span>Smurfs are the tood dudes</span>
<span>Not all smurfs are dudes</span>
<span>WHat is a Surf Smerf anyway?</span>
<span>I smurf this Smurf</span>
<span>Smurfs are the tood dudes</span>
<span>Not all smurfs are dudes</span>
<span>WHat is a Surf Smerf anyway?</span>
```